Isometric shift in disc algebra
Let $A$ be the disk algbra: Collection of all continuous functions on the closed unit disk which are analytic on the open unit disk, equipped with the supremum norm.
Now, consider the multiplication operator $M_z:A \to A$, defined by
$$M_z(f) = z.f, \qquad f\in A.$$
My claim is
(1) $M_z$ is an isometry,
(2) $A= \oplus_{n=0}^\infty M_z^n C$ where $C$ denotes the one-dimensional space of constant functions.Here the direct sum means that every element $f$ of $A$ can be uniquely expressed as $f=\sum_{n=0}^\infty M_z^n a_n$, for some sequence $(a_n)$ of complex numbers.
To prove the isometry, we argue as
$$\|M_z f\| = \|z.f\| = \max_{|z|\leq 1}|z.f(z)|$$
However, by maximum modulus principle, we have
$$\max_{|z|\leq 1}|z.f(z)|=
\max_{|z|= 1}|z||f(z)|=\|f\|.$$
Thus, $M_z$ is an isometry.
However, I am unable to prove the second part. I appreciate any help regarding the claim (2).

Isn't that just the Taylor series of $f$ decomposition?

Thank you for your comment @conrad. Will you kindly elaborate. Is the Taylor formula for f in A, gives a convergent series in A?

You are right that the Taylor coefficients do not work always but you are misstating the original claim
